# How do I secure my hls link so that no other site will use it

Tags: webserver, nginx, rtmp, hls

I made a streaming server using Nginx RTMP.

I installed it and tested it and it works fine but when I broadcast and use the m3u8 link on my site, I find that some sites can take it and put it there and it will work and this will consume my server resources.

I created a live streaming server using Nginx, according to the explanation in this link: [Create a secure adaptive bit-rate HLS stream with Nginx/RTMP/Ffmpeg on Ubuntu 20.04 (2021)](https://www.ustoopia.nl/featured/create-a-secure-adaptive-bit-rate-hls-stream-with-nginx-rtmp-ffmpeg-on-ubuntu-20-04-2021/).

I streamed on the server and used the file extracted from the stream
I mean this, for example: `https://mydomain/hls/stream/index.m3u8`

I put it in the video player on my site and it works fine.

The problem here is that anyone who uses the m3u8 file or link and puts it in a player on their site works.

I don't want that... I just want the broadcast to work on my website
I've seen many sites use this method to protect broadcasts from being stolen from other sites

I want when I open this link: `https://mydomain/hls/stream/index.m3u8` it doesn't work
I only want it to work if I add it in the video player inside my site.

My question is: How do I make the m3u8 link work only on sites I own?

Answer (score 0):

To restrict your web-server to serving your own sites only, block in
the firewall all sites except to the IP addresses of your sites.

You may do that on the computer or in the router.

More specific advice depends on your software.

Comment: how to do it ? What does my computer and router have to do with that?
My question is how to protect or encrypt the live broadcast when it works on a specific site?

Comment: Then I didn't understand the problem description. Could you please flesh-out your question with more details.

Comment: The post has been modified
More details have been added

Comment: There might be some confusion between "site" and "computer"?

Comment: On this point
"To restrict your web-server to serving your own sites only, block in the firewall all sites except to the IP addresses of your sites."

Is there any explanation or steps to do this on Nginx ?